# Calling fragment inside MainActivitySo

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented navigation drawer in my app. When I open the app first it shows blank screen. Instead I want it to start fragmentA.
I have tried

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, fragmentA.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but this gives me activity not found exception. 
So how can I start a fragment inside an activity?

Comment: have u mention that class name in maifeast

Comment: No. It is a fragment so is it cannot be defined as an activity right?

Comment: @VyprNoch how can you use startActivity with intent for fragment?

Comment: Yes thats what I needed to know. I know it is wrong but I wanted to know how to correct it.

Comment: extend with fragmentactivity and then mention in mainfeast dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.yourFrame, fragmentA.getInstance());
 fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in your activity

Comment: documentation here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Comment: Thanks I will go through it